# .ova oficial ubuntu openstack username password

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, ova

I have downloaded an .ova from openstack, specifically, the following:
http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/current/focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova
The problem is that the username and password to access the system is not reflected by any site.
I have searched for forums, on the internet, I have tried the typical admin, ubuntu, user, etc ...
Does anyone know the default credentials to access?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The account should be *ubuntu*. There is either no password, or it is displayed on the console when booting (or booting for the first time). You can use cloud-init to add user accounts and set passwords.

Comment: The username is not "ubuntu" and the password is not blank. I use an .ova file from the official ubuntu page: ubuntu-focal-20.04-cloudimg. Thank you

Comment: Again, you could use cloud-init to add user accounts, including their passwords. You could also check the contents of that image using the libguestfs (https://www.libguestfs.org) or similar tools.

Answer (score 0):

I unpacked the OVA file and copied the *passwd*, *group* and *shadow* files from it. You are right, there is no user *ubuntu*. In fact, the image doesn't seem to have a non-admin account at all, which is a bit surprising considering the Ubuntu practice of not having a root passwd. So I guess you have to create the account yourself, either with tools like guestfish or virt-edit, or by launching an instance with cloud-init.

Here is what I did to come to my conclusion:

```
# apt-get install libguestfs-tools
# wget http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/current/focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova
# tar xvf focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova
# qemu-img convert -O raw ubuntu-focal-20.04-cloudimg.vmdk ubuntu-focal-20.04-cloudimg.img
# virt-cat -a ubuntu-focal-20.04-cloudimg.img /etc/passwd /etc/group /etc/shadow >/tmp/passwd
# sed 's/^root/===========================================\nroot/'  /tmp/passwd
===========================================
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-network:x:100:102:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-resolve:x:101:103:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:102:104:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
messagebus:x:103:106::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
syslog:x:104:110::/home/syslog:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
tss:x:106:111:TPM software stack,,,:/var/lib/tpm:/bin/false
uuidd:x:107:112::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin
tcpdump:x:108:113::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:109:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
landscape:x:110:115::/var/lib/landscape:/usr/sbin/nologin
pollinate:x:111:1::/var/cache/pollinate:/bin/false
===========================================
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog
tty:x:5:syslog
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:
audio:x:29:
dip:x:30:
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
gnats:x:41:
shadow:x:42:
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:
sasl:x:45:
plugdev:x:46:
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:
users:x:100:
nogroup:x:65534:
systemd-journal:x:101:
systemd-network:x:102:
systemd-resolve:x:103:
systemd-timesync:x:104:
crontab:x:105:
messagebus:x:106:
input:x:107:
kvm:x:108:
render:x:109:
syslog:x:110:
tss:x:111:
uuidd:x:112:
tcpdump:x:113:
ssh:x:114:
landscape:x:115:
admin:x:116:
netdev:x:117:
lxd:x:118:
===========================================
root:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
sys:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
sync:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
games:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
man:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
lp:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
mail:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
news:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
uucp:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
proxy:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
www-data:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
backup:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
list:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
irc:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
gnats:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
nobody:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
systemd-network:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
systemd-resolve:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
systemd-timesync:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
messagebus:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
syslog:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
_apt:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
tss:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
uuidd:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
tcpdump:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
sshd:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
landscape:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
pollinate:*:18583:0:99999:7:::
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried installing OVA file using vSphere and were able to set password from "customize template" screen. Please find below screenshot for password set up.

[image]